# How to execute several tests with future

Tags: scala, concurrency, scalatest

I have a several Scala test with Future and with Await time and the same structure. Tests check some method which write file to file system.

I want to execute tests strictly consistent each test have to start after future in previous test will be finished. Could u help me find the way?

Now I have a failed test, because next test cant check result.

```
class Test1 extends AsyncFunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Eventually with Matchers {
       test("test 1") {
          // clean file system

          Try(
             Await.ready(
             Future(TestedMethod1.run(someArgs)), 10 seconds)
          )

           // checking file
      }

       test("test 2") {
         ..... // the same tests
      }
}

class Test2 extends AsyncFunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Eventually with Matchers {
       test("test 1") {
         ..... // the same tests
      }

       test("test 2") {
         ..... // the same tests
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`AsyncFunSuite`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.2/org/scalatest/funsuite/AsyncFunSuite.html) by default provides [serial execution context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62253093/5205022)

```
private final val serialExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = new concurrent.SerialExecutionContext
implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext = serialExecutionContext
```

which only has a **single** thread available so if that thread is blocked by `Await` then further tests cannot proceed. The solution is to refactor your tests to not use `Await` but instead simply map over the `Future` as usual

```
Future(TestedMethod1.run(someArgs)).map { result =>
   // assert on result
}
```

Note it is likely you can [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526334/5205022) using `Eventually`.

Comment: Thank u fro response, I rewrite test with map, but test execution did not finished. Is it cause that I use   implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)) ?